# Chromedriver emulation with selenium and node

Tags: node.js, selenium, mobile, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

Trying to setup e2e tests using emulation of mobile devices with chromedriver.  We are using chromedriver 2.3 on Mac OS and it appears that the supplied chromeOptions are not valid:

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var capabilities = {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
        mobileEmulation: {
            deviceName: 'Apple iPhone 5'
        }
    }
};

var driver = new webdriver
        .Builder()
        .withCapabilities(capabilities)
        .build();

driver.get('http://google.com');

var bool = false;
setTimeout(function () {
    bool = true;
}, 9000);
driver.wait(function() {
    return bool;
}, 10000);

driver.quit();
```

What am I doing wrong?  Here is the stack trace of the error:

```
UnknownError: unknown error: cannot parse capability: chromeOptions
from unknown error: unrecognized chrome option: mobileEmulation
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.3,platform=Mac OS X 10.10.1 x86_64)
    at new bot.Error (/Users/michael/cdTest/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/atoms/error.js:113:18)
    at Object.bot.response.checkResponse (/Users/michael/cdTest/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/atoms/response.js:106:9)
    at /Users/michael/cdTest/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:152:24
    at /Users/michael/cdTest/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/base.js:1582:15
    at webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runInNewFrame_ (/Users/michael/cdTest/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1654:20)
    at notify (/Users/michael/cdTest/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:465:12)
    at notifyAll (/Users/michael/cdTest/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:442:7)
    at resolve (/Users/michael/cdTest/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:420:7)
    at fulfill (/Users/michael/cdTest/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:535:5)
    at /Users/michael/cdTest/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/base.js:1582:15
```

Comment: 2.3 is over a year old. Any reason you are not using the latest version of chromedriver? If there is a reason, then please add it to your question.

Comment: I've tried the latest version, it shows the same error. I went back because I was thinking something in a newer version could be causing an issue.  The feature should be available in versions after 2.11???

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with Chrome Driver 2.9 and it works fine now since I replaced it with [the newest Chrome Driver 2.15](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads).

Comment: One thing to be aware of is device versions. I was able to reuse you're code, except I had to have Selenium open one Chrome window, then I inspected to see which iPhone versions I had to work with because  'Apple iPhone 5' threw an error until I changed it to 'iPhone 6/7/8 Plus'.

Answer (score 0):

this code definitely works in nodeJS and selenium-webdriver: ^4.0.0-alpha.1 and chrome 71; just mind that from time to time, the list

```
deviceName: 'Apple iPhone 5'
```

will change with new devices and older ones removed.